# sqlldr stream record format on commandline

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am loading a delimited file using sqlldr. I have kept file format/table details in the ctl file and pass other parameters on the command line.

```
sqlldr control=sp.ctl data=data.20170502.txt SKIP=1 userid=xyz@db/pwd log=sp.log bad=sp.bad
```

## sp.ctl

```
LOAD DATA

TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE "T_DATA"
TRUNCATE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
C_1 CHAR(2000),
C_2 CHAR(2000),
C_3 CHAR(2000)
)
```

I now need to use a stream record format on this data file.

```
infile 'example3.dat'  "str '|\n'"
```

However, I am not using the **infile** syntax.

So I tried using

```
sqlldr control=sp.ctl data=data.20170502.txt "str '!\n'" SKIP=1
userid=xyz@db/pwd log=sp.log bad=sp.bad
```

It gives an error:

> LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'data'

How do I pass the record delimiter on the command line?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using `INFILE` in your control file?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can, so instead perhaps look into a wrapper that generates a ctl file with the clause in and present that to sqlldr.

Comment: Take a look at: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8764530300346290066

Comment: Worked around like this: `LOAD DATA
infile 'dummy.txt'  "str '!'"` and then used the real data file name on commandline `sqlldr control=sp.ctl data=data.20170502.txt SKIP=1
userid=xyz@db/pwd log=sp.log bad=sp.bad`